# How do I split contents of a list that is part of a dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've got a dataframe where each row is a list of pairs. For instance, I've got a dataframe df that looks something like this:

```
id | pairs
1  | (a, b), (b, c), (a, c) 
2  | (a, b), (b, d) 
3  | (b, c) 

id: Int
pairs: Array<Struct<String,String>>
```

After the processing, the dataframe should look something like this:

```
pairs  |  
(a, b) |
(b, c) |
(a, c) |
(a, b) |
(b, d) |
(b, c) |
```

I don't really need the `id` column so a solution that discards all the other columns of the dataframe also works. Also please note that duplicates cannot be removed from the dataframe. If there are 3 instances of a pair, I need all 3 of them in my new dataframe.

I've tried individually iterating over the contents and adding them to a global list but this approach is too slow. (I'm eventually running a Spark job where I require this bit for some pre-processing.) Is there an efficient way of doing this without having to iterate over every single element of every list in every row of the dataframe?

Appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [drop](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#drop-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) function to remove the `id` column, and [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#explode) to create each tuple in a different row:

```
val initialDf= ....

val dfAfterDrop=initialDf.drop("id")
val dfAfterExplode = dfAfterDrop.withColumn("pairsExplode", explode($"pairs"))
```

Now your `pairsExplode` column has all the tuples, each tuple in a different row.
You can remove the original `pairs` column by using `drop` again.

---

More elegant way - thanks to @Hristo Iliev:

```
initialDf.select(explode($"pairs") as "pairs")
```

Comment: What about a simple `initialDf.select(explode($"pairs") as "pairs")`?

Comment: Yes, its more elegant :)